# Showing that a diffusion process is positive recurrent

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider an one-dimensional diffusion, with values in $(0,\infty)$, solution of the SDE

$$dX_t = \mu(m-X_t)dt + \sigma X^{\psi}_tdB_t$$

Where $B_t$ is a standard one-dimensional brownian motion, $m>0,\sigma>0,\mu>0,\psi \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $X_0 \in (0,\infty)$.

Show that

a) This diffusion is positive recurrent

b) The stationary measure $\pi$ integrates $x^q$ for $q \in \mathbb{R}$

For the positive recurrence, one usually looks at the scale function. The thing is that the presence of the term $X^\psi_t$ on the diffusion function confuses me when building the scale function. Any help or insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please write down the scale function and what exactly confuses you.

Comment: So, when computing the scale function I have $S(x)=\int^{x}_{0}exp(-2\int^{y}_{0}\frac{b(z)}{a^2(z)}dz)dy$. Where $b(x)$ is the function multiplying the $dt$ term in the diffusion and $a(x)$ is the function function multiplying the $dB_t$ term in the diffusion. The function $b(x)$ is clearly $\mu(m-x)$. But how can I write the function $a(x)$ in terms of x? Can I write something like $(x+\psi)$ instead of x (as the diffusion starts in $\psi$)?

Comment: The diffusion does not start in $\psi$. This is an exponent of $x$. So $a(x)=\sigma x^\psi$.

Comment: Oh, you are right! Sorry, this was confusing me as sometimes we represented a process $X_t$ starting at point $x_0$ as $X_t^{x_0}$. But in this case he states that $X_0$ is in $(0,\infty)$ so my logic makes no sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We start with the scale function

$$S(x)=\int^x exp(-2\int \frac{1-z}{z^{2p}}dz)dy=c_{2,p}\int^x exp\left(2c_{1,p}(2 p-1)y^{2 - 2 p}   -2c_{1,p} 2y^{1 - 2 p} \right)dy,$$

for $c_{i,p}>0$. This integral diverges as $x\to +\infty$ and so by Karatzas-Shreve 5.22 proposition we get recurrence in $(0,\infty)$.

As mentioned in [Lecture 10: Forward and Backward equations for SDEs](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture10_2019.pdf)
 the density $\rho$ for the stationary measure satisfies

$$\partial_{x}\left((1-x)\rho-\partial_{x}(x^{2\pi}\rho)\right)=0$$

$$(1-x)\rho-\partial_{x}(x^{2\pi}\rho)=c$$

which has the solution (from Wolfram-alpha)

$$\rho(x) = x^{-2p} exp(-(x^{1 - 2p} (2p (-x) + 2p + x - 2))/((2p - 2) (2p - 1)))$$
$$\cdot \int_1^x-c exp((\xi^{1 - 2p} (-\xi 2p + 2p + \xi - 2))/((2p - 2) (2p - 1))) d\xi $$
$$+ k_1 exp(-((2p (-x) + 2p + 2p - 2) x^{1 - 2p})/((2p - 2) (2p - 1)) - 2p \log(x)).$$